# EditText multiline not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have this XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textchat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

But, when I start to write on it, it stops after a number of characters. I would like to remove completely the character limit. Somebody knows how? Thanks.

EDIT: Complete XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ChatActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logotipo_high_density_vinceri_movil" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/home_high_density_vinceri_movil" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/alertas_high_density_vinceri_movil" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textchat"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo_chat_cuerpo_high_density_vinceri_movil"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="normal" 
    >

</ListView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textchat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLength="1000"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/chatbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textchat"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_btn_enviar_high_density_vinceri_movil" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the number of characters it stops after and what do you mean by "stops"?

Comment: It stops after 64 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you typing actual sentences into the edit text field?  I found that there is a 64 character limit on words.  So if you are just typing in random characters without spaces, it will appear as though you have hit the character limit for EditText, but you actually just hit the character limit for a word.

Comment: Was a long time ago, but thank you for the answer! I was actualy typing kjajdhuhi stuff, without spaces, and it stops after 64 characters...

Answer (score 6):

The following does it for me:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:singleLine="false"
```

Also when you set it in the code, make sure InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE bit is also set:

```
editText1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

Comment: Following this answer, but I omitted "android:singleLine" and it works too.
"android:singleLine" is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/textchat"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:maxLength="100"
    android:ems="10" >
```

set the maxLength limit what you want here `android:maxLength`

Comment: That sets the EditText to a normal EditText, with a character limit, the same I want to remove. But thanks, anyway.

Comment: you can use `android:maxLength="100"` or the limit you want to set??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textchat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:maxLength="1000" /> <!-- Practically not possible for a user to enter 1000 words -->
```

but the code you provided should work, your code works for me.

Comment: Did it, but still not working. Going to clean project, just in case Eclipse has gone mad.

Comment: No result. Weird. As you all can see, its a chat app. I tried to answer back a long text, just in case was a problem inflating the 9patch png, but the long answer (and it is pretty long) its presented ok. It's driving me nuts...

Comment: now that is strange. try `android:maxLength="10"` and see if it limits the number of character to 10.

Comment: Yes, it works, the EditText only admits 10 characters, but below, where the autocorrector (I don't know if it is said that way in english, I think you understand me) the rest of the characters can me seen. But not in the EditText. The EditText is below a ListView, I tried to delete the ListView to see is an issue with the EditText that cannot grow because of the ListView, but the result is the same. I have assured 10 times that it is the proper EditText. I am very confused!!

Comment: Going to try with emulator, instead of my device.

Comment: Using the emulator works perfectly!! Going to try with another device. I got a Sony Xperia... it is possible for that model to works incorrectly with this component?

Comment: Tried in the Samsung Galaxy III of my boss, and same result, it limits characters in the EditText. Don't know what to do...

Comment: can you post your complete xml file?

Comment: It's a very weird thing, as I said, in the emulator works cool, but not on the devices. I am using a Mac, could that matters?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by `david m lee` It's worked:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```